# need help in positioning

Tags: jquery

i am using "beassistance validation" for my form and using tooltip [plugin](http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery) and it work fine except that positioning.

please have a look at [this](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/9562/validationandhelp.png) link and i upload my form to get an idea what i am talking about.

what i want is:

if my validation fails i want to display the message **after** the tooltip icon, but its displaying the message **before** the tooltip icon. please see [here](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/9562/validationandhelp.png)

here is the .css i am using:

validation .css

```
 #aspnetForm
        {
            width: 670px;
        }
        #aspnetForm label.error
        {
            margin-left: 10px;
            width: auto;
            display: inline;
        }
        form.cmxform
        {
            width: 50em;
        }
        em.error
        { 
            background: url("Images/unchecked.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
            padding-left: 16px;
        }
        em.success
        {
            background: url("Images/checked.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
            padding-left: 16px;
        }
        form.cmxform label.error
        {
            margin-left: auto;
            width: 250px;
        }
        #aspnetForm label.error
        {
            background: url("Images/unchecked.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
            padding-left: 16px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #EA5200;
        }
        #aspnetForm label.checked
        {
            background: url("Images/checked.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
        }
        em.error
        {
            color: black;
        }
        #warning
        {
            display: none;
        }



<asp:Label runat="server" ID='Label8' >Start Date:</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat='server' ></asp:TextBox>
        <a style="cursor: hand" class="tooltip" title="Select the starting date of a visit, example 05/05/2010 (MM/DD/YYYY)!">
            <img alt="" src="Scripts/JQuery/Tooltip/icon_tooltip.gif" style="width: 11px; height: 11px" /></a>
        <p>
        </p>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID='Label9' >End Date:</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat='server' ></asp:TextBox>
        <a style="cursor: hand" class="tooltip" title="Select the end date of a visit, example 05/06/2010 (MM/DD/YYYY)!">
            <img alt="" src="Scripts/JQuery/Tooltip/icon_tooltip.gif" style="width: 11px; height: 11px" /></a>
```

tooltip.css

```
#tooltip{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background:#f7f5d1;
    padding:2px 5px;
    color:#333;
    display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add position:absolute; in #aspnetForm label.error css

Comment: its much closer but still not perfect, its the error is on top of the tooltip icon how can i move little bit right side?, i am no way css person.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to float:left your tooltip icon, thus making it appear at the left of error message...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any fields with an id of tooltip. Just a class. Your css should be
`.tooltip{}` Also, I would enclose the fields in a span, p or other similar inline element so you can predictably float your elements left as per Zuul's recommendation. IE:

EDITED:

```
<p class="form_row">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID='Label8' >Start Date:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat='server' ></asp:TextBox>
    <a style="cursor: hand" class="tooltip" title="Select the starting date of a visit, example 05/05/2010 (MM/DD/YYYY)!">
    <img alt="" src="Scripts/JQuery/Tooltip/icon_tooltip.gif" style="width: 11px; height: 11px" /></a>
</p>
<p class="form_row">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID='Label9' >End Date:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat='server' ></asp:TextBox>
    <a style="cursor: hand" class="tooltip" title="Select the end date of a visit, example 05/06/2010 (MM/DD/YYYY)!">
    <img alt="" src="Scripts/JQuery/Tooltip/icon_tooltip.gif" style="width: 11px; height: 11px" /></a>
</p>
```

Then css as:

```
.form_row {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
}
#aspnetForm label.error {
    float:right;
}
```

I used simple html elements in this example for simplicity sake as I am not too familiar with how asp creates those controls. But you get the idea.

EDITED:

The edits above will get you closer to what you want, but you might want to consider revising your element structure into something more maintainable.

Comment: i tried with your suggestions but it does not work, it messed up the positioning worst.

Comment: Try adding `float:right;` to `#aspnetForm label.error`. I actually need to see how the asp creates and names your controls.

Comment: i have implement float:right and it look better but its too far right, have a look at the screen shot please: http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/8998/floatright.png

Comment: Try the above. Hope it helps.